# Problem with "apt-get update" command!

Tags: apt, updates, gnupg

I can't update my ubuntu repository list, I try "`sudo apt-get update`" but I get this error:

```
Get:15 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [1,540 B]                                                                                                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Get:16 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,540 B]                                                                                                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable Release           
E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

Does anyone can help me to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get clean` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`.